# Error in auto.arima(y, xreg = x, trace = T) : xreg is rank deficient

Tags: r, arima

I am trying to run an ARIMAX model on Bitcoin in R and I want to find the best model by running the function `auto.arima()`.

My database contains open, close, high, low, volume and market cap. The dependent variable is the closing price and all the others are used as exogenous variables.

In my approach I firstly convert the entire database in a timeseries database using the function ts().
After that I select the Y and X for the auto.arima() function as follow:

```
fitarima <- auto.arima(y, xreg = x, trace=T)
```

But R returns me the error

```
in auto.arima(y, xreg = x, trace = T) : xreg is rank deficient.
```

Am I using the wrong approach?

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Please review my answer in your second question how to approach ts forecasting with regressor... I also supplied some links where the writer of the forecast package explains how it works. Also there is an openbook from the inventor of the forecast package, which explains very well how ts prediction should be done: https://otexts.com/fpp2/

Comment: If you can vote this question too I can vote your answers, thx